# Cocossharp Xamarin Pixel perfect collision detection

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, collision-detection, pixel-perfect

Im making a game for Android and iOS using Cocossharp in Xamarin. I have 2 `CCSprites` and I need to know if a pixel with color on one sprite is overlapping a pixel with color on the other sprite, but I cant seem to find a map or array containing the pixels on the `CCSprite` Object. Does anyone know if it exist? And where?
Or could someone just point me in the direction of an existing algorithm for such work usable in a shared project in Xamarin.

Comment: Looks like simple rectangle collection detection is possible via CCSprite's BoundingBox: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/cross-platform/game_development/collision